# Preventing indexoutofboundsexception in a 2d Array

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

just wondering what is wrong with my code. Hidden tests show that an invalid array index comes back as 'valid'.

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Check if the array index is inside the grid
 * 
 * @param x - row
 * @param y - column
 * @return true if given index is inside the grid; otherwise false
 */
public boolean validIndex(int x, int y)
{
    boolean result = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
        {
            if (i >= 0 && i < arr.length && j >= 0 && j < arr.length)
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }
    }
return result;
}
```

Comment: I dont think this code can throw `IndexOutOfBoundException` on it own. Post complete code.

Comment: This seems like an inefficient way of doing it - there's no need to loop through each array to find out if the index is valid or not.

Comment: Also, given the structure of the loops, this function will _always_ return `true` because both `i` and `j` will always be between 0 and `arr.length`

Comment: I use a nested for-loop as arr[][] holds objects.of type 'Cell'. I'm testing whether the coordinate of that particular Cell is valid or invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is ignoring the input `x` and `y` indices and always returns true (unless the input array has 0 rows).

Check the passed indices `x` and `y` instead of having those loops.

All you need is :

```
if (x >= 0 && x < arr.length && y >= 0 && y < arr[x].length)
    result = true;
```

Comment: yes, the 2d array is a grid of size = size * size (ie: a square grid)

Comment: @Khai Still, you are ignoring the input of your `validIndex` method.

Comment: As soon as I can, I will accept your answer. Thank you very much for your help!!!!